Cant seem the send data to certain group SignalR
Sending information to specific groups is not working
For a school project is was trying to send data to my frontend im working on. However when i try to do that i receive notting. When i change from a group to just all clients i do receive the data. So i dont know what is going on.
My application is basicly multiplayer tic-tac-toe. So its starts on the home screen when wanting to join a lobby:
<script lang="ts">
    import type { RoomDTO } from "$lib/DTO/RoomDTO";
    import { loginStore } from "$lib/store/loginStore";
    export let room: RoomDTO;

    async function handleJoin() {
        try {
            if ($loginStore.isLogged) {
                location.assign(`/room/${room.Id}`);
            }
        } catch (error: any) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }
</script>

<div class="room-card">
    <h2>{room.Name}</h2>
    <p>ID: {room.Id}</p>
    <p>{room.Users.length}/2</p>

    <button on:click={handleJoin}>Join kamer</button>
</div>

After this the user gets send to the gamepage. Here the player joins the signalR hub based on the guid given to the game room:
    public async Task JoinRoom(string roomId, string userName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(roomId) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userName))
        {
            await Clients.Caller.SendAsync("Error", "RoomId or Username required");
            return;
        }

        var succes = await _roomService.JoinRoom(Guid.Parse(roomId), userName);
        if (!succes)
        {
            await Clients.Caller.SendAsync("Error", "Room not found");
            return;
        }

        // Voegt gebruiker toe aan SignalR groep
        await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, roomId);
        
        // Stuur een bericht naar iedereen in de kamer
        await Clients.Group(roomId).SendAsync("UserJoined", userName);
    }

Here the user gets added to a group based on that GUID, However when i try and send the data to the frontend in the next code snippet i receive nothing, not even a simple string. But when i send i to all clients they receive the simple string:
    public async Task MakeMove(string roomId, string userName, int position)
    {
        var room = await _roomService.GetRoom(Guid.Parse(roomId));
        if (room == null)
        {
            await Clients.Caller.SendAsync("Error", "Room not found");
            return;
        }

        var isMoveValid = await _roomService.MakeMove(room.Id, userName, position);
        if (isMoveValid)
        {
            await Clients.Caller.SendAsync("Error", "Invalid move");
            return;
        }

        // Broadcast de nieuwe GameState
        var gameState = room.GetGameState();
        await Clients.Group(roomId).SendAsync("GameStateUpdated", "Random tekst om te testen");
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("GameStateUpdated", "Random tekst om te testen");
    }

These are the things i use to make the connection in the frontend:
ConnectionManager.ts:
import { HubConnectionBuilder } from "@microsoft/signalr"; 
import { PUBLIC_BASE_URL } from '$env/static/public'

const ConnectionManager = (hub: string) => {
    let connection= new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl(`${PUBLIC_BASE_URL}${hub}`, {
            withCredentials: true,
        })
        .withAutomaticReconnect()
        .build();

    return connection;
}

export default ConnectionManager;

gamehub.ts:
import ConnectionManager from "./connectionManager";

export default function GameHub(RoomId: string, UserName: string, onGameStateUpdated: (state: any) => void) {
    let connection = ConnectionManager('gamehub');

    // Event listeners configureren
    connection.on("GameStateUpdated", (state: any) => {
        console.log('State ontvange: ', state);
        onGameStateUpdated(state); 
    });

    // Starten van de verbinding
    const startConnection = async () => {
        try {
            await connection.start();
            await connection.invoke("JoinRoom", RoomId, UserName);
        } catch (err: any) {
            console.error(`Error connecting to SignalR: ${err}`);
        }
    };

    // Methode om een zet te doen
    const makeMove = async (index: number) => {
        try {
            await connection.invoke("MakeMove", RoomId, UserName, index);
        } catch (err: any) {
            console.error(`Error while making move: ${err}`);
        }
    };

    // Verbinding afsluiten
    const stopConnection = async () => {
        if (connection) {
            await connection.stop();
        }
    };

    return {
        startConnection,
        stopConnection,
        makeMove,
    };
}


And tha svelte.page itself:
<script lang="ts">
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    import { loginStore } from '$lib/store/loginStore.js';
    import { GameStateDTO } from '$lib/DTO/GameStateDTO.js';
    import Board from '$lib/components/board.svelte';
    import GameHub from '$lib/hubs/gameHub.js';
    export let data;

    const RoomId: string = data.id;
    let userName: string = '';
    let gameState: GameStateDTO = new GameStateDTO();

    // SignalR intialisatie
    let hub: any;
    onMount(() => { 
        loginStore.setup();
        userName = $loginStore.username || '';

        hub = GameHub(RoomId, userName, (state: any) =>{
            console.log("Gamstate: ", state);
            //gameState = state;
        });
        hub.startConnection();

        return () => {
            if (hub) hub.stopConnection();  
        };
    });

    async function makeMove(index: number) {
      if (hub) await hub.makeMove(index);
    }
</script>

<main>
    <Board
        {gameState}
        on:makeMove={(event) => makeMove(event.detail)}
    />
</main>

<style>

</style>

The guid's look something like this:
83860C03-E89C-4CCE-BA3F-47F5E6535183


Have you ever solved the problem? If not, you can try to set break point to check whether the following method is executed or not: JoinRoom, MakeMove, UserJoined and  GameStateUpdated. Besides, since you are using the room id as the room name, when join the room and send message, you can check whether the room id is same or not.
